# Как вывести рекламный блок на всех страницах?

Tags: html, ssi, php

В общем такое дело: у меня сайт написан на чистом HTML более 1000 страниц и естественно, если я хочу вставить рекламу на все страницы, то мне нужно вручную вставлять код рекламы на каждую страницу, а это, как вы сами понимаете, утомительно. Объясните, как сделать так, чтобы добавляя рекламный код в какой-то один файл, она выводилась на всех страницах. У меня хостинг работает с PHP, если что.

Answer (score 2):

На уровне идеи: дописать перед `</body>` ссылку на скрипт, выводящий рекламный блок. Тогда для изменения содержимого блока надо будет редактировать всего один файл. Разумеется, дописывать ссылку надо не вручную, а запустить разок php скрипт.

Comment: вобщем то мне было понятно что так и нужно делать да только вот скрипт написать не могу не умею. люди напишите мне для примера.

Answer (score 1):

Для достижения этого эффекта вы можете:

- Использовать шаблонизатор (и засунуть рекламный блок в шаблон)
- Использовать Include или require (require_once) на каждой страницы
- Использовать SSI
- Использовать директиву .htaccess

Comment: ага вот этого я и не умею (((

Comment: Да кстати переносить сайт в базу данных. 1000 страниц это жесть.

Comment: вообщето страниц если честно не 1000 а 1800 )))

Comment: Тем более переписывайте все. Пишите движок либо используйте готовый.

Comment: да и как перенести на базу данных я неумею и не вижу в этом смысла мож что непонимаю

Comment: и зачем вообще переносить. сайт работает отменно

Comment: Если я правильно понимаю то большая часть данных сайта - это статьи, либо табличные данные. Их вполне можно сунуть в таблицу и оттуда брать. Таким образом 1000 страниц превратится в 4-5 максимум. А вам не кажется что это уже геморрой править сайт из 1000 страниц? Особенно если вы будете менять дизайн?

Comment: единственное мне нужен скрипт чтобы добавлять на страницы рекламный код а то в ручную добавлять это точно жесть. размещал рекламу чуть не помер)))

Comment: А теперь представьте что при изменении рекламы придется все менять? Учите PHP, ASP, Pearl без разницы что или используйте готовые движки.
Игнорируя эту необходимость вы сами себе работу в будущем усложняете.

Comment: я не разбираюсь в програмировании только HTML поэтому сам состряпал как мог запустил раскрутил работает вот гляньте http://sema207.ru/

Comment: В принципе если менять дизайн для меня это 3 дня работы но конечно это трудоёмко но возможно. а если горорить например об установки CMS я как то ставил два сайта у меня чтото там крякнуло и весь сайт слетел несмог востановить поэтому для меня на HTML пока надёжнее проще востанавливать без потерь

Comment: Начните изучать php хотя бы, без этого бесполезно говорить о скриптах вставки рекламы.

Comment: нужно не говорить а просто написать скрипт и код вывода и всё. залил на сайт скрипт вставил в страницы и всё работает. если бы я знал php  я бы вопросы не задавал. а вообще заказывал видеоуроки по php начинал изучение ))) вот это геморой )))

Comment: у меня кстати форма обратной связи и форма заказа написана на php. но я её не создавал а просто слил готовые на какомто сайте вставил в страницы и всё работает. а вот скриптов для вывода рекламы на все страницы к сожалению не нашёл пока

Comment: Готовое есть на woweb.ru

Comment: там все инструкции на англиском переводчик не помогает

Answer (score 1):

Делаем файл adv.js
Подключаем его в <head> (<script src="adv.js"></script>)

В adv.js пишем что-то вроде:

```
window.onload = function()
{
    document.getElementById('ad_holder').innerHTML = "текст или хтмл код рекламы";
}
```

Таким образом реклама будет вставлена во все теги с id="ad_holder". 
Скрипт adv.js нужно подключить во все страницы и редактировать нужно только его.

Comment: Не понятно а какой код размещать в страницах чтобы выводилась реклама. в странице написать id="ad_holder" и всё ?

Comment: нет id="ad_holder" выводится просто текстом

Comment: Во-первых, вставка будет только в первый элемент с таким id, во-вторых, window.onload может использоваться только 1 раз на странице, второй вызов перезапишет первый, что не есть гуд. Реализация:
<pre>
Подключить jquery:
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.ad_holder').html('html code');
});
А на странице:
<div class="ad_holder"></div>
<div class="ad_holder"></div>
<div class="ad_holder"></div>
<div class="ad_holder"></div>
</pre>

Answer (score 1):

В общем, есть два решения: либо переписывать весь сайт, подключая админку и БД (предпочтительно), либо добавить js-скрипт на все страницы. По первому решению писать много и долго, а по второму все просто. Скачайте ваш сайт в папку на комп, откройте любой файл из корневой папки с помощью Notepad++ и произведите замену в файлах (включая подпапки): </body> на <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/ads.js"></script></body>. Пока идет замена, можете пойти попить чай (или спать, как повезет).
В папке /js создайте файл ads.js - в нем будет вывод рекламы. Примерный код:

```
var b = document.createElement('div');
b.id = 'adblock';
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(b);
b.innerHTML = 'йа рекламко';
```

Ну и не забудьте создать крутилку рекламы и стилизовать блок на странице.

Comment: ваш ответ тоже не полный. примерный код это не конкретно а я не програмист. создать крутилку не умею я не програмист. да и крутилка мне не нужна.

полный атас

Comment: Тогда просто замените `йа рекламко` на ваш html-код. А вообще, это - знак, что пора бы взяться за web-программирование. На чистом html'е далеко не уедешь.

Comment: всё сделал да только ерунда получается так как выводится только снизу сайта с лева. а мне нужно чтобы выводилась там где я хочу. я вставил в текст а она всё равно выводиться снизу сайта. нужен другой скрипт.

Comment: А вы про css слышали?

Answer (score 0):

о_О 1800 страниц на чистом html.. jo22, мне вас искренне жаль ='(

Но если правда не лень, то как вариант вот вам: пусть в файле adv.php контент с рекламой, баннер например. И во все файлы вставить содержимое сего файла. прописать где нужно

```
<?php include_once "adv.php"; ?>
```

однако в таком случае нужно будет все 1800 файлов (даже от мысли такой плохо становится:D) сохранить не как .html, а как .php, но если вам не лень потратить на дизайн 3 дня вместо 3 минут, то думаю такой вариант в самый раз для вас. Потом просто менять будете содержимое adv.php и реклама будет соответственно изменяться на всех страницах сайта.

Можно написать скрипт, который пройдется по всем файлам и вставит что нужно и куда нужно.

Comment: У меня все страницы проиндексированы, поэтому переделывать расширение на php не буду, а в html ваш код, к сожалению, не работает.

Answer (score 0):

В Дримвивере есть функция ( найти и заменить ) в разделе ( правка ). с помощью этого окна можно вставить, любой див блок сразу по всему сайту автоматически. Например - найти контент и заменить на контент + ваш див блок и выбрать функцию заменить по всему сайту